# MyEclipse 7.5 SVN Plugin Installation not working

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

```
I have myeclipse 7.5 and i want to install svn plugin.

When i enter  Name: Subclipse URL:  http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x in the add site it give this error 


 This profile can not be resolved because required software could not be located.
  Could not locate installable unit:   org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not locate installable unit: org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.graph.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not locate installable unit: org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not locate installable unit: com.collabnet.subversion.merge.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not locate installable unit: org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not locate installable unit: org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group 0.0.0
  Could not load update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4
  Could not load update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede
  Checked update site http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/7.0/updates and found 816 installable units.
  Checked update site http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/7.0/updates/supporting and found 21 installable units.
  Checked update site http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/jdks and found 6 installable units.
  Checked update site http://downloads.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/products/pulse/client and found 116 installable units.
  Checked update site http://downloads.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/products/pulse/ganymede and found 104 installable units.
  Checked update site http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/eclipse/updates/3.4 and found 1809 installable units.
  Checked update site http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/releases/ganymede and found 2420 installable units.
  Checked update site http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/products/pulse/client and found 116 installable units.
  Checked update site http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/products/pulse/eclipse34 and found 1 installable units.
  Could not load update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x
  Checked update site http://www.poweredbypulse.com/pulse/download/live and found 1 installable units.
```

And when i search Subclipse in search of add, still it wont install. Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

In MyEclipse you should use the Configuration Center to install plug-ins. `Help` -> `MyEclipse Configuration Center`.